# Is it possible/advised to store a vector in a struct? C++

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I always have thought of a struct as a fixed sized object and while there doesn't seem to be any glaring compiler errors, I was wondering if doing this is generally in good practice. Would changing the struct to a class be more advisable or will a struct do just as well?

The code, just because people get fussy:

```
struct Sprite
{
    float x;
    float y;
    std::vector<Sprite> sprite;
}
```

The essence of what I am doing is having children of a class as the same type as the parent. When the parent dies, the children do too.

Comment: A `struct` is just a class with a default visibility of `public` instead of `private`.

Comment: Note that adding members with contructor/destructor to a struct makes the compiler emit a constructor/destructor for the struct as well. C-style techniques that imply POD structures won't work.

Comment: Storing a vector inside the struct doesn't make it change its size. Vector's items are stored on the heap, so the size of the struct remains the same, no matter if the vector has 0 or 1000 elements.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An `std::vector` has a specific known size, and any class or struct that contains it has a specific known size. `std::vector` allocates memory on the heap to act as a variable sized array and stores a pointer to said memory. The only difference between a struct and a class is that a struct is defaultly public, and a class is defaultly private.

Comment: Thank you. That definitely makes sense that the vector would only serve as a pointer to the memory in heap. Thanks for the detailed reply.

Answer (score 7):

The differences between `struct` and `class` have to do with member visibility: the most notable difference is that `struct`'s members are public by default, and also that `struct`'s inheritance is public by default; `class` members and `class` inheritance are both private by default. Other than that, there is no difference: you can always write code with `struct` that produces code equivalent to code written with `class`, and vice versa.